# App distributed via store fails to activate

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-10, monogame

I have a MonoGame project for Windows 10. It succesfully builds, and runs on several dev machines. However, when I submit it to the store and users install it, the game fails to activate.

The game shows the App splash screen for a moment, then closes and leaves behind the logs below in event viewer under Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational.

**Event viewer log 1:**

> Activation via contract helper of the app ! App for the
>   Windows.Launch contract failed with The remote procedure call failed..

**Event viewer log 2:**

> Activation of the app !App for the windows.Launch contract
>   failed with error: The Remote procedure call failed..

**Additional Info:**
The app is currently distributed to a few testers via private package flights. These users cannot run it.
I can replicate this, by getting a clean install of windows and then adding it's account to the package flight group.
However, if I sideload the same package that was submitted to the store, something on the computer changes. After uninstalling the sideloaded version, I can then download and run the windows store package flight correctly and get to gameplay.

I suspect a security issue related to the contents of the app.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to declare a PackageDependency in the appxmanifest? Take a look at the side-loading script and see if it adds any framework package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cause is most likely the AppSimulator.

Asking this for license information on a non-developer machine throws a generic exception on startup that is probably the issue you are having.

Comment: That was it! I found a call to the app simulator that was getting hit in release, after removing that it is all fixed. Thanks.